# Groovy string parsing into groups

Tags: groovy

I'd like to parse a string of the form `"xx;yy;zz%;tt"` into groups, where `;` is the delimiter character, and `%` is the escape character. So that in this example it becomes a list of 3 elements with `[xx,yy, zz;tt]`.

I know of the split method, but it doesn't take an escape character, and it seems like I need a lot of lines and temporary variables to achieve the wanted result. Is there a short way to do this, with closures ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a regex with a negative lookbehind to match all semicolons not preceded by a percent sign:

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "xx;yy;zz%;tt"
    def arr = test.split(/(?<!%)\;/)
    println(arr)
}
```

prints:

`[xx, yy, zz%;tt]`

You have to use the lookbehind in order to prevent characters that precede the semicolon from being captured by the regex.